# Where does the Buddha say 'you will be punished by your anger'?

Tags: reference-request

I've heard this quote attributed to the Buddha

> You will not be punished for your anger, you will be punished by your
>   anger

Does anyone know where the quote comes from? Also the The notion of punishment seems a bit non standard to me. Does anyone know the orginal term (Pali etc...) translated here as punishment and if this is an accurate translation. I do like the quote though hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The fakebuddhaquotes web site attributes it](http://www.fakebuddhaquotes.com/you-will-not-be-punished-for-your-anger-you-will-be-punished-by-your-anger/) as follows:

> Going back to 1993, we hit pay dirt! In *To Love Is to Know Me: The Bhagavad Gita for Daily Living* (Volume 3), author Eknath Easwaran says the following:
>
> > Even more intriguing to me is the karma of our health. Again, let me illustrate one or two kinds of connection. For one, the Buddha says that **we are not punished for our anger, we are punished by our anger**. In other words, anger is its own karma.
>
> Note the absence of quotation marks. Eknath is not quoting the Buddha, but paraphrasing his teachings on anger and karma.